# Request events - Does the requestListener in http.createServer(requestListener) need to be a function with two parameters (request, response)?

Tags: node.js

As far as I understand `createServer` is a function that accepts a single parameter: a function which will execute every time there is a request.

Does this function `requestListener` in `http.createServer(requestListener)` need to be a function with exactly two parameters (request, response) or be a function that includes a function call to a function with the arguments (request, response)?

Also does the code `response.end()` need to be called in order for a request to properly complete?

Comment: are you referring to the first or second question?

Comment: Consider using http://expressjs.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can pass any function you want.
   However, if you want to do anything useful, you will need to use both parameters.
2. Yes; every response must be ended.

Comment: Thanks! How does `http.createServer` know if the function you're passing takes 2 objects as arguments (response, request) instead of a different function that takes two arguments that are strings?

Comment: @user784637: Your question doesn't make sense.  Javascript function parameters don't have types.  If your function assumes that its parameters are strings, HTTP will pass `req` and `res` anyway, and your code may break.

Comment: Also - why do you need both parameters if say you only wanted to call `response.end()` and not use the request object for anything?  It seems if you specify a single argument `response` to the request listener, an error is thrown.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't know http is expecting `req` and `res`.  Is that in the documentation somewhere? I couldn't find it here http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener

Comment: @user784637: It's right there.  `The requestListener is a function which is automatically added to the 'request' event.` and, somewhat later, `Event: 'request'#
function (request, response) { }

Emitted each time there is a request. Note that there may be multiple requests per connection (in the case of keep-alive connections). request is an instance of http.IncomingMessage and response is an instance of http.ServerResponse`

Comment: @SLaks Where is the documentation on requestListener's parameters? For example what are the properties on Request and Response objects?

Comment: @styfle: `request is an instance of http.IncomingMessage and response is an instance of http.ServerResponse`  http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse

Comment: @styfle Sadly, you are living in a dream world where APIs have actual reference documentation that you can refer to when programming, a la typical javadoc.  Now you have to piece it all together from some combination of the actual bare-bones documentation (more a discussion than a reference), stackoverflow, and judicious use of JSON.stringify and console.log().  Big time-waster, and not conducive to the production of high quality code, imo.

Comment: @jarmod I think I found some IDEs/plugins that can help with documentation in the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5045889/266535).

Comment: @styfle That's a great point.  I have largely given up on IDEs, well Eclipse anyway because it is so wretched, but am toying with IntelliJ and the like.